# Receiving "push is not a function" on JS reducer result array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following function that retrieves an array of playlists then attempts to build a simplified version in a new array using a reducer on the fetched array.

The first iteration shows that paredPlaylists contains a single element that looks like I expect.  On the second, it instead becomes a Promise and then gives the error

> paredPlaylists.push is not a function

I understand that the error itself is explained by the resulting array (paredPlaylists) no longer being an array, but a promise.  But how does it successfully push the simple object {id: "foo"} onto the array in the first pass then get converted to a promise in the second?

```
async function getPlaylists(token) {
    return await fetch('https://somewhere')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(async (response) => {
            return await response.items.reduce(async (paredPlaylists, playlist) => {
                await paredPlaylists.push({
                    "id": "foo"
                })
            }, [])
        })
}
```

Note: I'm still pretty new to React and JS and have only partially gotten a grasp on promises and forcing async.  I expect I have a number of awaits that are unnecessary.  Early attempts did not have so many, I just kept peppering them to hopefully get actual objects to work with vs. promises.

Comment: If you're manipulating the `fetch` result only by reducing it as `{"id": "foo"}` probably you don't need all of these `async/await` but just the first one, with the return (even if, `return await` doesn't make much sense)

Comment: @CapitanFindus Thank you.  I'm still wrapping my head around JS' async model and most of those were indeed extraneous add-ins based as much on trying to fix the wrong interpretation of the symptoms.

Comment: you're welcome. If you want a simple explanation of my sentence "return await doesn't make much sense" you can [check this out](http://hassansin.github.io/Why-return-await-Is-a-Bad-Idea)

Answer (score 2):

the [reduce fn](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes an array and run a callback for each item.
If you're working with an array of array consider using the concat

```
  return response.items.reduce( (a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
```

If it's just an array, then just map your items as u prefer

```
  return response.items.map(playlist => ({ id: playlist.id }) )
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had taken more notes on the mechanics of how to call reduce than the results and use cases for them.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm still getting the original issue using concat (yes, it's going to be adding a more complex object that itself contains an array).  The accumulator array is getting initialized to [] and is an array of one object:  [{id: "foo"}] after the first iteration, but on the next pass it is undefined.

Comment: could you update your question with an example of what the response.items looks like, and be a little more descriptive on what you're trying to achieve?